Css isolation asp net mvc not working, file {ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css not found (404)
I'm working on a project here using ASP NET MVC with .NET 8 version
For the first time my asp net mvc project experienced an error file {ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css not found (404).
I've done several projects using ASP Net MVC and isolated CSS files always work, just add {ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css to the top of the layout file.
I've tried looking for several solutions via stackoverflow, github discuss and some AI GPT, but I can't find what the problem is the file {ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css is not found
Maybe someone can help or provide advice, I would really appreciate it.
Below I provide several pictures and links to supporting articles :
*How to use CSS Isolation in ASP NET / Blazor :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0
*This is my code declaring CSS isolation <link href="~/LokerAdminMVC.style.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />, my project name is LokerAdminMVC

This is how the error displays in the console and network browser:


If anyone can provide advice or anything, I would be very grateful

So that's looking for a file in the www folder named LokerAdminMVC.style.css - is there one there? I suspect probably not and would suggest using the file picker. When you type ~ in the link it should come up with a helper to make sure you pick a file. Hope this helps.

I am hosting/referencing a Razor Class Library in MVC (.NET 8).
I had to use the following for the CSS Isolation to work.  This appears to have changed recently.
<link href="~/_content/{ASSEMBLY NAME}/{ASSEMBLY NAME}.bundle.scp.css rel="stylesheet>

Note the words "bundle.scp" in the link reference.
